# CloudFlare URL Forwarding Returns Error 520

Tags: redirect, dns, cloudflare, cname, http-status-code-302

Our company recently changed domain names. Both the new and old domain have their DNS zones managed by CloudFlare and I'm having difficulties redirecting the old domain to the new one.

The new domain is setup and working correctly. I want a rewrite rule which forwards all incoming requests on the old domain to the new one.

```
(http|https)://old.com/dir/page => https://new.com/dir/page
```

The DNS Zone on the old domain looks like this:

```
CNAME     @     new.com
```

I also setup a Page Rule to which should forward all requests to the new demain

```
*.old/* => https://new.tv/$2  (302 redirect)
```

Still, requesting the old domain returns an error 520.

We're migrating today and would greatly appreciate help to resolve this.

Thanks